# Using recursion to iterate over XML file

Tags: php, xml, recursion

I am having an issue with a recursive function I am trying to work on.  I have an XML file that essentially documents a file/folder structure.  These XML nodes (which represent a file/folder) can be N levels deeps.  So, I am trying to write a script that iterates over all the nodes and creates entries into a database.  For the folders, I have a table structure that has an ID, field_name, and parent_id columns.  The parent_id points to the ID of a folder the current folder resides in.  If it's at the root level, the ID is 0.

My problem is that I'm not able to accurately keep track of the parent_id, when I get down lover levels, then comes back up.  Here is an example of XML, but realize the folders can be any number of levels:

```
<XML>
    <programs>
        <program name ="xxx">
            <groups>
                <group id ="1" name ="yyy">
                    <folder name = "ggg">
                        <file name = "ddfdf"/>
                        <file name = "ddfdf"/>
                        <folder name = "sub" />
                    </folder>
                    <folder name = "sdfsdfs">
                        <file name = "ddfdf"/>                  
                        <folder name = "sub" >
                            <file name = "ddfdf"/>
                        </folder>       
                    </folder>
                </group>
            </groups>
        </program>
    </programs>
</xml>
```

Script:

```
   foreach($program as $p){
       //creates root folder and returns ID
        $id = create_folder($folder);
        $rootId = $id;
        $groups = $program->groups;
        if($p->groups){
            foreach($p->groups as $group){
                foreach($group as $folder){
                        process_folder($folder,$id, $rootId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

function process_folder(($folder,$id, $rootId){
    foreach($folder as $key=>$value){
        switch ($key){
           case "folder":
                //creates folder, then returns the ID of the db record
                $parentId = create_folder($folder);
                process_folder($value, $parentId, $rootId);
                //reset ID but this doesnt seem to work
                $parentId = $rootId;
                break;
            case "file":
                break;
        }    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution but it shows how a recursiveIterator might be used to accomplish what you want to do.

```
    $strxml='
    <xml>
        <programs>
            <program name ="xxx">
                <groups>
                    <group id ="1" name ="yyy">
                        <folder name = "ggg">
                            <file name = "ddfdf"/>
                            <file name = "ddfdf"/>
                            <folder name = "sub" />
                        </folder>
                        <folder name = "sdfsdfs">
                            <file name = "ddfdf"/>                  
                            <folder name = "sub" >
                                <file name = "ddfdf"/>
                            </folder>       
                        </folder>
                    </group>
                </groups>
            </program>
        </programs>
    </xml>';

    class RecursiveDOMIterator implements RecursiveIterator {
        private $index;
        private $list;

        public function __construct(DOMNode $domNode){
            $this->index = 0;
            $this->list = $domNode->childNodes;
        }
        public function current(){
            return $this->list->item($this->index);
        }
        public function getChildren(){
            return new self( $this->current() );
        }
        public function hasChildren(){
            return $this->current()->hasChildNodes();
        }
        public function key(){
            return $this->index;
        }
        public function next(){
            $this->index++;
        }
        public function rewind(){
            $this->index = 0;
        }
        public function valid(){
            return $this->index < $this->list->length;
        }
    }



    $xml=new DOMDocument;
    $xml->loadXML( $strxml );
    $rootnode=$xml->getElementsByTagName('programs')->item(0);

    $nodeItr=new RecursiveDOMIterator( $rootnode );
    $itr=new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $nodeItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
    foreach( $itr as $node ) {
        if( $node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) {
            $id=$node->hasAttribute('id') ? $node->getAttribute('id') : false;
            $attr=$node->hasAttribute('name') ? $node->getAttribute('name') : false;
            echo $id.' '.$node->nodeName . ' ' . $node->nodeValue. ' ' . $attr .' '.$node->parentNode->tagName . ' ' . '<br />';
        }
    }
    $dom=$rootnode=$itr=$nodeItr=null;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've tried to implement what you have but the loadXML always turns up empty.  Even just doing $doc->loadXML('<root><node/></root>'); will produce an empty object.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Is there a reason why my code wouldn't work?  If there was a way to keep track of the correct parent folder id?

Comment: Strange that the above didn't work for you - I just copied the above exactly and created a new php page with only that code and it worked fine. Turn on error reporting to see if anything is going awry on your setup.

Comment: Yeah, it is strange.  I'm not getting an error.  Its just that when I debug, and use loadXML, even with a simple string, the object is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using XSLT to simplify your XML to a one child level format. Then run a simple PHP loop to extract parent id and folder data for database migration. In fact, if using MySQL you can import this exact transformed XML document into database with [LoadXML()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html), should node names match column names.

As information, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is a special-purpose, declarative programming language (same type as SQL) used to re-structure XML documents to various structures for end use needs. Like all general purpose languages including C#, Java, Python, Perl, VB, PHP maintains an XSLT processor. Below is an XSLT script (which you can add to for each nest in XML document) and PHP script (to transform and iterate through output).

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl or .xslt)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="folder" name="foldertemplate">
    <row>      
      <parent_id>0</parent_id>      
      <field_name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></field_name>      
    </row>

    <!-- ADD LEVELS FOR EACH NEST IN XML DOCUMENT -->
    <row>
      <parent_id><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></parent_id>      
      <field_name><xsl:value-of select="folder/@name"/></field_name>      
    </row>

    <!-- EXAMPLE NEXT LEVEL -->
    <!-- <row> -->
    <!--   <parent_id><xsl:value-of select="folder/@name"/></parent_id> -->      
    <!--   <field_name><xsl:value-of select="folder/folder/@name"/></field_name> -->    
    <!-- </row> -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**TRANSFORMED XML OUTPUT** *(easier to parse and iterate over)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <parent_id>0</parent_id>
    <field_name>ggg</field_name>
  </row>
  <row>
    <parent_id>ggg</parent_id>
    <field_name>sub</field_name>
  </row>
  <row>
    <parent_id>0</parent_id>
    <field_name>sdfsdfs</field_name>
  </row>
  <row>
    <parent_id>sdfsdfs</parent_id>
    <field_name>sub</field_name>
  </row>
</root>
```

**PHP** Script *(to transform and loop through output)*

```
// Set current directory
$cd = dirname(__FILE__);

// Load the XML source and XSLT file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($cd.'/Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($cd.'/XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// Transform XML source
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// Save output to file
$xmlfile = $cd.'/Output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);    

// Load new XML with SimpleXML
$newdoc = simplexml_load_file($cd.'/Output.xml');

$data = [];
$node = $newdoc->xpath('//row');
$parents = $newdoc->xpath('//row/parent_id');
$folders = $newdoc->xpath('//row/field_name');    

// Loop through folder names and parent
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($node); $i++) {        
    echo 'parent: '.$parents[$i]. ' folder: ' . $folders[$i]."\n";    
}

#parent: 0 folder: ggg
#parent: ggg folder: sub
#parent: 0 folder: sdfsdfs
#parent: sdfsdfs folder: sub
```